# Why is Poisonous plants stack solution giving TLE?

Tags: python, algorithm, stack

Trying to solve [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/poisonous-plants/copy-from/20479326) problem.

There are  plants in a garden. Each of these plants has been added with some amount of pesticide. After each day, if any plant has more pesticide than the plant at its left, being weaker than the left one, it dies. You are given the initial values of the pesticide in each plant. Print the number of days after which no plant dies, i.e. the time after which there are no plants with more pesticide content than the plant to their left.

I have used stacks to solve this problem. Example below:

```
a = 6 5 8 4 7 10 9

10 > 9   a = 6 5 8 4 7 10    b = 9

7 > 10   a = 6 5 8 4 7       b = 9

4 > 7    a = 6 5 8 4         b = 9

8 > 4    a = 6 5 8           b = 9 4

5 > 8    a = 6 5             b = 9 4

6 > 5    a = 6 5             b = 9 4
```

after this just make a new list with `a = a + b.reverse()`. Start the process again and exit when list is sorted in reverse order.

This still is giving me time exceeded. Any idea?

```
n = int(input())
first_list = input().split()
first_list = [int(i) for i in first_list]
count = 0
second_list = []
data_1, data_2 = 0, 0
while True:
  b = []
  if sorted(first_list, reverse=True) == first_list:
    break
  data_1 = first_list.pop()
  for i in range(len(first_list)-1):
    data_2 = first_list.pop() 
    if data_1 > data_2:
      pass
    elif data_1 < data_2:
      second_list.append(data_1)
    elif data_1 == data_2:
      second_list.append(data_1)
      second_list.append(data_2)
    data_1 = data_2
  if len(first_list)>=1 and data_1 < first_list[0]:
    first_list.append(data_1)
  second_list.reverse()
  first_list = first_list + second_list
  count += 1
print(count)
```

Edited code:

```
n = int(input())
input = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
count, t_length = 0, 0
cmp = input[0]
while True:
  length = len(input)
  for i in range(1, length):
    if input[i] == -1:
      t_length += 1
      continue
    if input[i] > cmp:
      cmp = input[i]
      input[i] = -1
    else:
      t_length += 1
      cmp = input[i]
  if t_length+1 == length:
    break  
  count += 1
  cmp, t_length = input[0], 0
print(count)
```

Comment: Does hackerrank give better scores when you use meaningless variable names like `a` and `b`? If not, why do you do it?

Comment: This looks to be at least O(n^2) [if you replace the sorts with a linear-time check] . Given the input list can be 100,000 in length, perhaps you need to discard your idea that it can be solved using a simple approach and find a smarter method?

Comment: A linked list doesn't change (as far as I can tell) anything fundamental about how the algorithm works, although it does look like a promising way to speed up your code by a constant factor -- although you might achieve the same using a regular array and removing the elements in-place as you iterate through the values for a particular day. Certainly you don't want to sort each time. Whether any of the optimizations are enough to get your code running fast enough to pass the hackerrank test is hard to know. My guess is they aren't, but it depends whether the test inputs are particularly nasty.

Comment: The problem is labelled "difficult" by hackerrank, so I'd guess you have to find something that's better than a heavily optimized but brute force algorithm.

Comment: @PaulHankin: added new code. This passed some more test cases but still giving TLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Woot4Moo that something doesn't look right, and I suggest you focus more on stack use (instead of doubly linked lists). See [this link to the Stock Span problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-stock-span-problem/) which helps detail an `O(N)` solution for tracking differences in a list of prices. This can be extended with a condition for pesticide.

For example, it'd be filling in the gaps of:

```
import sys

ps = [int(s) for s in list(sys.stdin)[1].strip().split()]
stack = [ps[0]]
max_days = 0
for i in range(1, len(ps)):
    days[i] = 1 if ps[i] > ps[i-1] else 0

    # TODO - Logic to update days[i] 
    while len(stack) > 0 and ps[i] <= stack[-1][1]:
        (ps_other, days_other) = stack.pop()

    stack.append((ps[i], days[i])
    max_days = max(max_days, days[i])

print(max_days)
```

I quickly implemented in `O(N^2)`, and found 80% of tests pass (the rest timing out), so more cleverly using the stack according to the link above should do the job.

```
import collections
import sys

ps = [int(s) for s in list(sys.stdin)[1].strip().split()]
ps_prev = []
days = 0
while collections.Counter(ps_prev) != collections.Counter(ps):
    ps_prev = ps[:]
    i = len(ps) - 1
    while i > 0:
        if ps[i] > ps[i-1]:
            ps.pop(i)
        i -= 1            
    days += 1      

print(days - 1)
```

---

**Edit**: note that the sketchy sys.stdin use is to cater for the HackerRank test input.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is `N log N` and your data structure seems wrong to me.  Why would you not use a doubly linked list since the requirement is that it is the left most neighbor.  You would simply dereference the pointers that died.

Comment: @nomanpouigt how is `your data structure seems wrong to me` then I explain the data structure to use cryptic?

Comment: @nomanpouigt so your code times out correct, hence the TLE?  You are doing unnecessary sorting with your stacks.  A doubly linked list solution will be N (no sorting necessary) and no extra storage necessary (unless you count overhead of doubly linked list).

Comment: I understood that part now. Looks like I was giving this problem unnecessary credit for being difficult. I can simply solve it with a simple list without using stacks. I will wait for some more comments before marking this answer as correct.

Comment: @nomanpouigt sure let me know if the stack solution is insufficient as I spent roughly 2 minutes thinking about it haha

Comment: this problem was under stack data structure. So i thought that the best solution has to be using stacks. This could have implemented with just a simple python list where when the data is no longer needed can be marked with a unique value. Same as in your case deleting a node.

Comment: added something better than double linked list approach. Have a look.This is passing some test cases but still not all.